# Golang gin: serving JSON and static files in the same app

Tags: go, go-gin

I am writing a golang gin app that serve both REST API and static files. Ideally I should separate the backend and front-end logic but for this case I have to put them together. For example, the top-level path of the API is wild-card, like http://myapp.com/{username}/{topic}, and this same endpoint can also serve a few reserved static resources like http://myapp.com/js/app.js, or http://myapp.com/css/style.css.

I understand this is not the best practice and I should separate the front-end code, but there are some other non-technical challenges in my case. Gin has a way to serve static files from a folder, but I would like to serve specific "reserved" path that point to a few known resources (JS, CSS, fonts, etc). How can I do that with GIN?

I can use the Gin template to serve the index.html, but couldn't figure out how to do it with the rest of the resources.

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/75

Answer (score 5):

Place files in respective folder (e.g. `.css` files in css folder, `.js` files in js folder etc) and place all these folders in assets folder. And use

```
router := gin.Default()
router.Static("/assets", "./assets")
```

Your end points will be `http://myapp.com/assets/js/app.js`, or `http://myapp.com/assets/css/style.css`
[check documentation](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#serving-static-files)

Comment: This doesn't work because I already have a path defined as router.GET("/:path1", getPath1), and router.GET("/:path1/:path2", getPath2), and gin will panic with error "wildcard route ':path1' conflicts with existing children in path '/:path1' when I add the router.Static("/assets", "./assets"). That is, because I already have path segment defined as wildcards, I cannot use the router.Static without conflicts, a quirky decision GIN has designed for. I am hoping that I can find a way to serve each of the individual static files from the wildcard handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
go get https://github.com/gin-contrib/static
```

Then import it:

```
import (

 "github.com/gin-contrib/static"
  
 )
```

Use this:

```
router.Use(static.Serve("/assets", static.LocalFile("./templates", false)))
```

Create a css and js folder inside templates and place the .css and .js files there

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/{FileName}.css">
```

To load the .css file

NOTE: It won't work without the "/" before "assets"